# Running canopy-script.pyw gives traceback "No module named canopy.app.bootstrap"

Tags: enthought

I am trying to follow instruction from [Enthought support website](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469810-Windows-Canopy-shortcut-in-Start-menu-doesn-t-do-anything) To test of what I have done i run line:

```
_python.exe  canopy-script.pyw -d
```

Unfortunately this gives Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "canopy-script.pyw", line 776, in <module>

File "canopy-script.pyw", line 336, in bootstrap

File "canopy-script.pyw", line 363, in chainload

File "canopy-script.pyw", line 762, in _chainload

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\Canopy-script.pyw", line 7, in <module>
from canopy.app.bootstrap import main  
ImportError: No module named canopy.app.bootstrap
```

After "Search" I can see many of bootstrap.py files on the disc.
What would be the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Canopy is 2.1.9. (You are running v 1.7.4).

To update Canopy, and for a link to release notes, please see ["Installing a new Canopy version"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version).

After you update, see:
https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021798791--UnresolvableRequirements-or-Conflicting-requirements-when-installing-or-updating-packages